# Jsoup get data next to element

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to get the data next to the hr tag. How would I accomplish this with JSoup? Is there a method that allows me to loop through all hr tags?

```
<HR>
Level: <B>Undergraduate</B><BR>
College or School: <B>College of Engineering and Applied Sciences</B><BR>
Department or Program: <B>Computer Science</B><BR>
<HR>
Level: <B>Undergraduate</B><BR>
College or School: <B>College of Engineering and Applied Sciences</B><BR>
Department or Program: <B>Computer Science</B><BR>
<HR>
```

My expected value would be

```
Level: <B>Undergraduate</B><BR>
College or School: <B>College of Engineering and Applied Sciences</B><BR>
Department or Program: <B>Computer Science</B><BR>

Level: <B>Undergraduate</B><BR>
College or School: <B>College of Engineering and Applied Sciences</B><BR>
Department or Program: <B>Computer Science</B><BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the `<hr>` tags by using [`document.getElementsByTag("hr")`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag-java.lang.String-).

From there you can iterate through the returned [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) to get each individual `<hr>`.

To get elements next to the `<hr>`'s you can use [Element.nextSibling()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#nextSibling--) to get adjacent nodes.